# What is a sequence of ordinals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, ordinals

What is a sequence of ordinals?

The concept of a sequence of ordinals shows up [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814978/definition-of-limit-of-a-sequence-of-ordinals) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3681409/strictly-increasing-sequence-of-ordinals-indexed-by-a-regular-cardinal-textc), and in the definition of cofinality in Jech, third edition, page 31.

> $\text{cf}(\alpha) =$ the least limit ordinal $\beta$ such that there is an increasing $\beta$ sequence $\langle \alpha_\xi : \xi < \beta \rangle $ with $\lim_{\xi \to \beta} \alpha_\xi = \alpha $.

For what it's worth, I found the Kunen definition of cofinality [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4031351/definition-of-cofinality-motivation) to be easier to understand, reproduced below. $\text{type}$ is the order type. (Basically, we're looking at the powerset of $\gamma$ and seeing how big of a powerset we need to limit to $\gamma$ itself. I think the Jech definition has the same idea, we're just ordering the subsets of $\gamma$ with their intrinsic ordering).

$$ \text{cf}(\gamma) = \min \{ \text{type}(x) : x \subset \gamma \land \sup(x) = \gamma \} $$

Anyway, I think part of the reason that I was initially thrown off by the Jech definition is that I think of sequences as being functions $\mathbb{N} \to X$ for some set $X$.

A sequence is this setting is clearly more general, possibly a function $\kappa \to X$ for some ordinal $\kappa$.

There are other choices we could make though: we could restrict $\kappa$ to be a cardinal, we could restrict $\kappa$ to be a limit ordinal, or we could allow $\kappa$ to be any order type, ordinal or not. I could also insist that $\kappa$ is a [directed set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set) and make myself a nice [net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)).

**What do people commonly use a sequence of ordinals to mean? What's the most restrictive definition I could take for starting out with set theory that's still broad enough to include sequences I'm likely to encounter?**

Comment: Note that the quoted text **doesn't** just say "sequence," it explicitly says "$\beta$ sequence." In general barring further context I read "sequence" as "function with domain $\omega$" and "$\beta$ sequence" for $\beta$ an ordinal as "function with domain $\beta$." But there are also definitely times where "sequence" is used as shorthand for "$\beta$-sequence for some ordinal $\beta$," that is "function with domain some ordinal." Certainly however this is moot as far as the quoted text goes: I think "$\beta$ sequence" is pretty unambiguous.